# Escape html in template PlayFramework

Tags: scala, templates, playframework

I'd like to escape a HTML in my template, but no matter what I try it won't work

Here is my template:

```
<ul>
    @for(index <- 0 until appointments.size){
    <li>
        @(utils.DateUtil.getLocalDate(appointments(index).getStartDate())) - @appointments(index).getReason()
<ul>

@{val procedure = appointments(index).getProcedures()

    {if(procedure == null){
    <b>Empty</b>
} else {
    "&gt;b/&lt;NotEmpty&gt;/b&lt;" +
    procedure.size().toString+
    procedure.size().toString+
        <b>NotEmpty</b>+
    "<b>NotEmpty</b>"+
    "<b>NotEmpty</b>".toString;
}
}


            }


        </ul>

    </li>
    }

</ul>
```

The problematic code is in the else branch

I'm trying to print  `<b>NotEmpty</b>` as **NotEmpty** but I've got just a plaintext, not html

I've tried `@Html("<strong>Do not escape</strong>")` but it says `expected start of definition`

if I delete the else branch contents and leave just

```
else {
    <b>NotEmpty</b>;
}
```

It prints out fine.
I'm using play framework 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_25)

Comment: Just use css to make the text bold.

Comment: it's not about making the text bold it's about printing out html tags, for example: <p> some text </p>  or <div> some elements </div>

Comment: Hm just curious why you use `for` loop like this ? isn't `@for(appointment <- appointments)` better ? Also use `@if{}else{}` etc . try to convert to standard Play syntax first and check if this resolves your problem

Comment: I had to change the syntax because I'm declaring a local variable in the block -> @{val procedure = appointments(index).getProcedures()

Comment: and how about `@defining(appointments(index).getProcedures()) { procedure => <b>@procedure</b> }`?

Comment: I've tried `else {
    <b>NotEmpty </b> 
    <a href="">{procedure.size().toString}</a>` and it seems to be working, I'll just run some more tests, thank you for your input
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```scala
@{
  val x = Some(Seq("hi there")) 

  if(x.isDefined)
    <b>size = {x.get.size}</b><br/>
    <b>Not Empty</b>
  else
    <b>Empty</b>
}
```